# How to add elements to a global array from a callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying querying and adding users to a global array from my database. I am trying to store the elements in a global array to I can access it from anywhere

```
app.get("/admin/orders", (req, res) => {
  Quote.find({}, (err, quotes) => {
    var products = [];
    var users = [];
    quotes.forEach((quote) => {
      User.findOne({ email: quote.user }, (err, user) => {
        if (!err) {
          users.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
    res.render("orders", { quotes: quotes, users: users, products: products });
  });
});
```

I am not getting any error from the database, and am getting my users back. When i try to log the array I get an empty array.

Comment: since the callback to User.findOne is **asynchronous** the users array will be empty at the time of `res.render`

Comment: Would be better to use mongoose promise based methods here and Promise.all().... or async/await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having such same issue in my express project. I have tried this trick to make it working. Added an index counter inside the loop:

```
app.get("/admin/orders", (req, res) => {
  Quote.find({}, (err, quotes) => {
    var products = [];
    var users = [];
    quotes.forEach((quote, index) => {
      User.findOne({ email: quote.user }, (err, user) => {
        if (!err) {
          users.push(user);
        }
        if (index+1 == quotes.length)
        {
            return res.render("orders", { quotes: quotes, users: users, products: products });
        }
      });
    });
    
  });
});
```